# Back projecting a 2D pixel from an image to its corresponding 3D point.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, projective-geometry, computational-geometry, computer-vision

I have been trying to understand how to project a 3D point to 2D image and vice versa. I had images of a building taken by a drone, I reconstructed the building using [COLMAP](https://colmap.github.io/)(an SFM tool). For those that are not aware, COLMAP, 3D reconstructs the entire scene, populates a point cloud and the camera poses for each image in the dataset. So, after running it through COLMAP, I have the following things available to me:

1. A scaled point cloud of the scene.
2. Transformations(R, t) from the world coordinate system to each camera coordinate system.

Just to get more intuition about the process, I am trying to project the pixel back to world**(at a scale)** using Camera Pose and Camera Intrinsics. I just need a unit vector in the right direction to the 3D point and not the absolute 3D point coordinate.

Here is my current understanding of the approach:

```
R_inv = R.T
M_inv = [R_inv | -R_inv*t]
# also augment M_inv with horizontal vector [0 0 0 1] so it's size is (4,4)
p= [u, v, 1]
p_camera = K_inv * p
p_camera_homogeneous = [p_camera[0], p_camera[1], p_camera[2], 1]
P = M_inv * p_camera_homogeneous
```

Here P = [X, Y, Z, W], so, Point in 3D is: (X/W, Y/W, Z/W). But when I plot the points in 3D graph, I don't get the correct structure. I understand I am missing something fundamental in my approach as I do not have a scale parameter in my equations too.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. I can share the code, but the problem is with my understanding of the concept.

Notes: "x.T" represents transpose of a vector x

Comment: The image is a projection.  So, in principle, you cannot find the 3D point corresponding to a certain pixel in the image, because all points lying on the line connecting the original 3D point with the pixel in the image will have that same pixel as their image.

Comment: Right, I don't intend the find the 3D point, I just want a ray(unit vector) in the direction of that 3D point.

Comment: You need to use several points in the 2D image to determine the projection - parallel (direction) or point (camera). Just from one point you cannot do.

Comment: @Moti can you explain a bit more, not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: To use a 2D image to determine projection affine projection techniques are used. Basically, the approach is determining the nature of projection by evaluating 4 points in the 2D presentation with known 3D locations. From this all-object projection could be determined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to formulate the problem I was trying to solve(I will update the question's details) and came up with a working solution. Before mentioning my approach, I would like to clear my confusion regarding the *Camera Extrinsic* and *Camera Pose*.

*Camera Pose* is the camera's location/orientation w.r.t the world whereas its *Extrinsics* are inverse of Camera Pose Transformation. What COLMAP provides is the Camera Pose for each of the images taken by the camera. For projecting a 3D point in the camera plane, one would use *Camera Extrinsics* whereas for projecting pixels out to the world, one needs *Camera Pose*. Here is how I approached the problem:

1. I manually(later automated) selected the pixels of interest and stored them in a list, *List2D*.
2. Augmented the *List2D* (*nx2* array) for homogeneous coordinates(*nx3* array).
3. Tranform each pixel coordinate, *p* in Camera frame using inverse of camera intrinsic matrix, *K*.

   > p<sub>c</sub> = K<sup>-1</sup> p
4. Transform the point, p<sub>c</sub> from camera frame to world frame, using the Camera Pose, T = [R | t]

   > p<sub>w</sub> = T p<sub>c</sub>
5. Transform the camera origin, *cam_origin = (0,0,0)* from camera frame to world frame

   > cam_origin<sub>w</sub> = T cam_origin
6. Get a unit vector, *v* along the ray passing from the camera origin to the 3D point. Our 3D point of interest lies along this ray. To traverse on this ray, we can parametrize the vector and move along this ray.

Code for implementing all of the steps is as:

```
def Get3Dfrom2D(List2D, K, R, t, d=1.75):
# List2D : n x 2 array of pixel locations in an image
# K : Intrinsic matrix for camera
# R : Rotation matrix describing rotation of camera frame
#     w.r.t world frame.
# t : translation vector describing the translation of camera frame
#     w.r.t world frame
# [R t] combined is known as the Camera Pose.

List2D = np.array(List2D)
List3D = []
# t.shape = (3,1)

for p in List2D:
    # Homogeneous pixel coordinate
    p = np.array([p[0], p[1], 1]).T; p.shape = (3,1)
    # print("pixel: \n", p)

    # Transform pixel in Camera coordinate frame
    pc = np.linalg.inv(K) @ p
    # print("pc : \n", pc, pc.shape)

    # Transform pixel in World coordinate frame
    pw = t + (R@pc)
    # print("pw : \n", pw, t.shape, R.shape, pc.shape)

    # Transform camera origin in World coordinate frame
    cam = np.array([0,0,0]).T; cam.shape = (3,1)
    cam_world = t + R @ cam
    # print("cam_world : \n", cam_world)

    # Find a ray from camera to 3d point
    vector = pw - cam_world
    unit_vector = vector / np.linalg.norm(vector)
    # print("unit_vector : \n", unit_vector)
    
    # Point scaled along this ray
    p3D = cam_world + d * unit_vector
    # print("p3D : \n", p3D)
    List3D.append(p3D)

return List3D
```

In the code above, a constant scaling factor for each pixel is used, which is not right but worked well for my case of defining a structure of the object in interest, though it was warped as points that were supposed to be farther away from the camera, were scaled by the same factor. For exact 3D model recovery, true depth for each pixel is required. Hence, instead of same scale factor, (*d* in the code), depth value for the corresponding pixel can be used.

As I continue to explore this topic in more detail, I will keep the answer updated with the results from this approach.

**Updates**: (COLMAP: Github: https://github.com/colmap/colmap/issues/1476)

Colmap's camera poses transform from world to camera coordinates, not the other way around. This leads to correctly oriented point clouds but I still see some offsets. Attaching images with results from previous understanding on Left and current on right.

[image: Consecutive Sequence]

[image: Random images in dataset]

**Final Update**: In the answer, I mentioned that COLMAP provides camera poses for each image, and that is the source of error as I went with the traditional definition of the term. I opened up an [issue](https://github.com/colmap/colmap/issues/1476) on GitHub to realize that COLMAP provides Camera poses that transform from world to camera coordinates. So, instead of passing [R,t] directly from COLMAP, I now pass [R.T, -R.T@t] to my Get3Dfrom2D() function and everything aligns:

[image: Consecutive Sequence - Aligned]

[image: Random images in dataset - Aligned]

There can be further improvements to filter the point cloud, reading the refined intrinsics for each camera etc.

Comment: PS: I projected 3D points from some selected 2D pixels in different image poses. Interestingly, these 3D points from different images were not aligned. I am wondering why that would be! It looks like the individual point clouds need to be transformed, though not sure why! Combined Point cloud [here](http://tinyurl.com/5n7rrzu3)

Comment: Camera poses are different and I thought I had already accommodated for that while finding the ray, hence, confused. If anybody stumbles upon this and knows what's wrong, let me know!